# Correct pattern to insert or update existed entity with spring data reactive

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I implement an application with spring data (mongo).

- It gets data from external service
- Store it to DB
- If item does not exist I'd like to insert it to db
- If item exists but has same md5 hash with external item - do nothing
- If item exists in DB and md5 hashes are not equal I'd like to update it

I have the code

```
public Mono<Void> processItems() {  
  return externalService.getItems() //this returns Flux<Item>
         .flatMap(this::createOrUpdateItem)
         .flatMap(itemRepository::save)
         .then() 
}

private Mono<Item> createOrUpdateItem(Item item) {  
  return itemRepository.findById(item.getId) //this returns Mono<Item>
          .flatMap(itemFromDb -> updateItem(itemFromDb, item))
          .defaultIfEmpty(item) 
}

private Mono<Item> updateItem(Item itemFromDb, Item item){
  if(itemFromDb.getMd5.equals(item.getMd5)){
     return Mono.just(itemFromDb);
  }

  itemFromDb.setName(item.getName)
            .setDescription(item.getDescription); 

  return Mono.just(itemFromDb);
}
```

How does it work:

- If item does not exist it stored in db
- If item exists and has same md5 hash updateItem returns existed in db and version in DB increases
- If item exists and md5 hashes are not equal updateItem set feilds and returns existed in db and version in DB increases

**The problem is**: when md5 hash are equal I don't want to cal DB. Because it increases version of the item in db but there were no changes.
How to properly implement this algorithm?

I can use @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "id") but not sure if it is a right way

Answer (score 1):

The only missing ingredient in your example is to continue with an empty stream if nothing needs to be done.

This solution is actually similar to yours, but has a clear separation of concerns.

The first `flatMap` only loads existing data. The second one contains only the business logic to decide what to do. It's up to you to follow these established principles ([Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), [Integration Operation Segregation Principle](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-1-red/#Integration_Operation_Segregation_Principle_IOSP) etc.).

```
public Mono<Void> processItems() {  
  return externalService.getItems() //this returns Flux<Item>
         .flatMap(this::loadExistingItem)
         .flatMap(this::setupOperation)
         .flatMap(this::saveItem)
         .then() 
}

private Mono<List<Item>> loadExistingItem(Item item) {  
  return itemRepository.findById(item.getId)
           .map(fromDb -> Arrays.asList(item, fromDb))
           .defaultIfEmpty(() -> Arrays.asList(item, null));
}

private Mono<Item> setupOperation(List<Item> items) {
  Item newItem = items.get(0);
  Item existingItem = items.get(1);

  if (existingItem == null) {
    return Mono.just(newItem);
  }

  if(newItem.getMd5().equals(existingItem.getMd5())){
    return Mono.empty();
  }

  existingItem.setName(newItem.getName)
  existingItem.setDescription(newItem.getDescription);

  return Mono.just(existingItem);
}
```